# How to install react-native on OSX with binary source?

Tags: macos, react-native, package-managers, watchman

I am trying to install `react-native` in osx. To do that, I am installing `watchman` on my machine. However I do not use `port` or `brew`.

Here is what I did.

1. Install `libtool-2.4.6`
2. Install `automake-1.9`, `autoconf-2.69`
3. Install `glib-2.52.2`

Now I am facing following message when I `./autogen.sh` on `glib`.

```
aclocal:configure.ac:72: warning: macro `AM_SILENT_RULES' not found in library
autoreconf: running: /usr/local/bin/autoconf --force
configure.ac:72: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_SILENT_RULES
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:88: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DEFINE
autoreconf: /usr/local/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

Is there other way to install `react-native`(or `watchman`) on OSX without `brew` or `port`.

FYI, I know how `brew` is convenient, but I just do not like to manage packages automatically. To me, `brew` , `port` seem like kind of plugin, not an essential - So I do not want to use those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to install this with source file way, but it seems like meaningless resistance. I did install `brew`. :(

you can install `watchman` with `npm install -g watchman` but it will not work. It is OK when install, but when you run `react-native`, it occurs an error with `EMFILE`.

Please, reply if you know how to detour this problem.(means not using package manager)